# what is HTTPS URL to iframe player

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

I am using twitter cards.

When using summary, photo twitter cards i have no problem.
But I am stuck in creating correct "player cards"

I have appliedtwo times for it and two times my card got rekjecte. I am thinking that My code is having some problem.

here is the code(meta tags)  I am using for twitter cards.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="player">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@PSPKFans_in">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@PSPKFans_in">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Atharintiki Daredi BGM">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Pawan Kalyan's Atharintiki Daredi BGM">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://www.pspkfans.in/wpimages/wp04cbbd0a_06.png">
<meta name="twitter:player" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/AD_Bgm.mp3">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="">
<meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="">
<meta name="twitter:player:height" content="200">
<meta name="twitter:player:width" content="600">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="www.pspkfans.in">
```

I am not sure what is https url of iframe player so i gave this link.

```
  <meta name="twitter:player" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/AD_Bgm.mp3">
```

Please help me in writing correct meta tags for player card.! https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fv8V.png

Comment: same problem with me, did your card got approved?

Comment: No not yet. This one is in initial stage. Please let me know If you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented this before however I have spent time looking at the [Twitter Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup) and saw your post. Your problem is two fold:

1. You are not specifying an iframe URL for this tag but rather the source file:

   `<meta name="twitter:player" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/AD_Bgm.mp3">`
2. You need to set the source URL of your video in this tag:

   `<meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="">`

You are putting the source in the player tag and not using the source tag at all. In order for this to work I would hazard that you should have an iframe page created and hosted on your website that contains this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.pspkfans.in/AD_Bgm.mp3"></iframe>
```

Save the above to, for example, `https://www.pspkfans.in/video.html` and then change your tags as follows:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="player">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@PSPKFans_in">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@PSPKFans_in">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Atharintiki Daredi BGM">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Pawan Kalyan's Atharintiki Daredi BGM">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.pspkfans.in/wpimages/wp04cbbd0a_06.png"> <!-- This is correct -->
<meta name="twitter:player" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/video.html"> <!-- The link to your iframe html page -->
<meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="https://www.pspkfans.in/AD_Bgm.mp3"> <!-- source file contained in iframe -->
<meta name="twitter:player:height" content="200">
<meta name="twitter:player:width" content="600">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="www.pspkfans.in">
```

The following tags below I removed or edited above because Twitter doesn't appear to use them anymore.

```
<meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="">
<meta name="twitter:image.src" content="http://www.pspkfans.in/wpimages/wp04cbbd0a_06.png">
```

The thing I can not be sure of is if you actually need to have your own, hosted video/audio player in the iframe or if Twitter will convert it. I would guess that your site should be hosting it's own player (hence the need for the iframe tag) and probably why you're card won't work. But give this a bash and see.